# How to build Laravel REGEX query including paginate

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Following query works fine in phpmyadmin, but I didn`t get figured out, how to put this into Laravel Eloquent with a request:

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE company REGEXP '\\MyCompany Corp\\b'
```

How do I have to create Laravel query if MyCompany Corp is search request like $search->search ??
Thank you for helping out.

Comment: can you use `like` operator to build you mysql query like `select * form customers where company like '%MyCompany Corp%'`. If so, then you can easily build with eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
->where('company', 'regexp', "$search->search")
```